# How to separate street name from address?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to use regex to separate street names, as well as street types (like Rd., Ave., Blvd) with regex, however, I'm stuck.

For example, If I type `'123 Main St.'`, I want it to return:
`['123', 'Main', 'St.']`.
Or if I type `'234 South 4th St.'`, I want it to return:
`['234', 'South 4th', 'St.']`.

How would I go about accomplishing this? This is what I have so far:

`re.split(r'(?<=\d)(?:-\d+)?\s+', "23rd South 4th St.")`

It returns:
`['234', 'South 4th St.']`.
However, I'm trying to get the `'St.'` in a separate index, too. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Have you looked at [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)?

Comment: Please include a wider sample of inputs, if that would be relevant.  For example, is every street named `St.`?  Or, could there also be `123 Main Blvd.`?  You need to cover your edge cases here.

Comment: `re.split('(?=[A-Z])', s)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re
def split_address(address):
  return re.match(r'(\d+)\s(.*)\s(?<=\s)(.*)', address).groups()

split_address("123 Main St.") # ('123', 'Main', 'St.')
split_address("234 South 4th St.") # ('234', 'South 4th', 'St.')
```

This works for both of your specific examples but keep in mind that you [might be assuming too much.](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^(?P<number>\d+)(?:th|[rn]d|st)?\s+(?P<street_name>.*?)\s+(?P<street_type>\S+)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zSeGsw/1). Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?P<number>\d+)` - Group "number": one or more digits
- `(?:th|[rn]d|st)?` - an optional group matching either `st`, `nd`, `rd` or `th`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?P<street_name>.*?)` - Group "steet_name": any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?P<street_type>\S+)` - Group "street_type": one or more chars other than whitespace
- `$` - end of string.

**[Python demo](https://ideone.com/dlNyBX)**

```py
import re
text = "23rd South 4th St."
match = re.match(r'(?P<number>\d+)(?:th|[rn]d|st)?\s+(?P<street_name>.*?)\s+(?P<street_type>\S+)$', text)
if match:
  print(match.groupdict())
# => {'number': '23', 'street_name': 'South 4th', 'street_type': 'St.'}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.